# REST API Delete request and update pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest

I have a question regarding the DELETE endpoint in my REST API.

To give a bit of context, in my frontend I have a 'clients' table with serverside pagination, so whenever I change page I send a request to the server which returns an object like the following:

```
{
    "items": [{id: 1, name: 'foo'}, {id: 2, name: 'bar'}, {id: 3, name: 'buzz'}],
    "itemCount": 3,
    "totalItems": 56,
    "pageCount": 19,
    "next": "http://localhost:3000/api/clients?page=2&limit=3",
    "previous": "",
    "currentPage": 1
}
```

When I delete or modify a client, I would like to return an updated version of the clients list, but I'm not sure whats the best way to do this without sending information on the **page** and **limit per page**.

The solutions I thought of to solve this issue are:

- I could send the information of the page and limit per page with the requests and retrieve the information in my delete endpoint after deleting the client. However, this seems very inefficient because I would be adding this extra info to endpoints not only for clients but for other models as well, as I have the same issue with products for example.
- I could send a delete request on my frontend and when that finishes make a request to get the updated information separately (maybe even in parallel?). But this seems inefficient as well due to the extra network request.

What would be the best way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I would recommend sending another `GET /clients` request to fetch the updated data rather than relying on the `DELETE` endpoint to give you that data. That way, you keep your `GET` and `DELETE` logic separate and you don't have to repeat yourself in the code of your API.

This approach might seem wasteful but it also feels cleaner and can be leveraged by the consumers of your API to programmatically refetch data a la GraphQL/Apollo (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#refetching).

If you are concerned about performances, you can also add caching to your API (with `node-cache`, for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache or AWS Redis: https://aws.amazon.com/redis/) to send responses faster for previously seen queries.

There is no REST API standard but, from experience, it is pretty common for `DELETE` endpoints to be as stateless as possible and return an empty body with a status code of `204` (see https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#http-status).

Hope it helps! Keep up with the good work :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My main concern was that having 2 separate network requests might impact performance, but caching the data is a great idea. I think that's a good solution so I'll give it a go!

Comment: Great! If the answer works for your problem, please select it as an appropriate response to help others who might have a similar issue :)